# Ignoring the first line of stderr and keeping stdout intact

Tags: bash, mongodb, stdout, stderr

`mongodump` prints a single debug message to stderr every time it is run, which is causing some unintended side effects. How do I ignore only the first line of stderr and keep everything else intact?

I'm piping stdout to a file, so I can't combine stderr and stdout.

Comment: What side effects are you referring to?

Comment: @chepner: Cron is sending me an email every time it runs, even though there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

Using a process substitution, and piping stdout into `rev` to see that stderr is unaffected

```
{  echo stderr1 >&2; echo stdout1; echo stderr2 >&2; } 2> >(sed 1d >&2) | rev
```

```
1tuodts
stderr2
```